# Passing Aggregation to a Linq Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have several queries that are pretty much the same except that the aggregation is different.  I am trying to create a method where I can pass the aggregation function.  My effort so far looks like

```
public void ExecQuery(Func<IEnumerable<testtable>, float?> filter)
{           
    var results = from a in testtable
                  group a by a.TransactionDate.Month into j
                  select new
                  {
                      Month = j.Key,                              
                      Total = filter
                  };
}
```

I would then like to be able to call it using

```
ExecQuery(c => c.Sum(a=>a.Price));      
ExecQuery(c => c.Count());
```

I think I am pretty close.

Comment: Why don't you make the method return an `IQueryable` and then add the filter when you get `IQueryable` by calling the method?

Comment: I have a lot of other code that is also common which isn't in the sample above.  I could also move that to a different method I guess and follow your idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your too close friend, try the following it should fix things for you:

```
 public class testtable
 {
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

    public float? Price { get; set; }
 }

 public List<testtable> tests = new List<testtable>();
```

Your method now should look like:

```
public void ExecQuery(Func<IEnumerable<testtable>, float?> filter)
{
   var results = from a in tests
   group a by a.TransactionDate.Month into j
   select new
   {
      Month = j.Key,
      Total = filter(j)//actually this the little update needed here
   };
}
```

In order to test our code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tests.Add(new testtable() { Price = 10, TransactionDate =new DateTime(2018,1,1,0,0,0) });
        tests.Add(new testtable() { Price = 20, TransactionDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0) });
        tests.Add(new testtable() { Price = 30, TransactionDate = new DateTime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0) });
        tests.Add(new testtable() { Price = 40, TransactionDate = new DateTime(2018, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0) });
        ExecQuery(c => c.Sum(a => a.Price));
        ExecQuery(c => c.Count());
    }
```

Then the result of the method should be:

for the sum : `{ Month = 1, Total = 30.0 } and { Month = 3, Total = 70.0 }`

for the count: `{ Month = 1, Total = 2.0 } and { Month = 3, Total = 2.0 }`

Also one comment here please use `decimal` for price it is more common and better for financial quantities.

Hope this helps :)